# Why does Hyper-V not enable this VMSwitchExtension?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, vswitch

The long and short of it is:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VMSwitch vSwitch

Name    SwitchType NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
----    ---------- ------------------------------
vSwitch External   Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-VMSwitch vSwitch).Extensions


Id                  : E7C3B2F0-F3C5-48DF-AF2B-10FED6D72E7A
Name                : Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform
Vendor              : Microsoft
Version             : 10.0.14393.0
ExtensionType       : Filter
ParentExtensionId   :
ParentExtensionName :
SwitchId            : 8082228e-905b-4967-bee9-e19deb3e2fc2
SwitchName          : vSwitch
Enabled             : False
Running             : True
CimSession          : CimSession: .
ComputerName        : EBBOX
IsDeleted           : False

Id                  : EA24CD6C-D17A-4348-9190-09F0D5BE83DD
Name                : Microsoft NDIS Capture
Vendor              : Microsoft
Version             : 10.0.14393.0
ExtensionType       : Monitoring
ParentExtensionId   :
ParentExtensionName :
SwitchId            : 8082228e-905b-4967-bee9-e19deb3e2fc2
SwitchName          : vSwitch
Enabled             : False
Running             : True
CimSession          : CimSession: .
ComputerName        : EBBOX
IsDeleted           : False

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-VMSwitchExtension -Name "Microsoft NDIS Capture" -VMSwitchName vSwitch | select-object Enabled

Enabled
-------
   True


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VMSwitchExtension vSwitch -Name "Microsoft NDIS Capture" | Select-Object Enabled

Enabled
-------
  False
```

In other words, I can't enable this VMSwitchExtension, or it continually disables itself. This also happens in the Hyper-V management UI for the virtual switch (I set the checkbox, hit ok or apply, close the dialog, reopen the dialog, and the checkbox is unset).

I am relatively unfamiliar with both Hyper-V and Powershell, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I noticed the same thing. When set, it continually disables itself.